# Утечка памяти в Python `threading`

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, память

При реализации многопоточности, используя `threading.Thread` наблюдается утечка памяти. У кого-нибудь есть идеи, как с этим бороться?

`Python 3.7.3 [GCC 8.3.0] linux Debian Stable`

Тестовый код:

```
# Аккуратно!!! Течет память!!!
import itertools as itr
import threading
from queue import Queue
import gc

class SimpleThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, queue, result):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.name = name
        self.result = result

    def run(self):
        while True:
            item = self.queue.get()
            self.result.append(set(item))
            self.queue.task_done()

class Calculate:
    def __init__(self, thread_cls, threads=16):
        self.result = []
        self.queue = Queue()
        for i in range(threads):
            t = thread_cls(f'№{i}',
                self.queue, self.result)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()

    def __call__(self, input_array):
        for i in input_array:
            self.queue.put(i)
        self.queue.join()
        return self

arr = list(itr.combinations(range(1, 30), 6))
while True:
    calc = Calculate(SimpleThread)
    calc(data)
    i = input('Нажмите `q` для выхода, или `Enter` для продолжения:')
    del calc.queue, calc.result, calc
    gc.collect()
    if i == 'q':
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо добавить способ остановки потоков, иначе у вас создаются потоки и остаются жить до завершения всего приложения. При этом каждый поток ссылается на очередь, тем самым не давая gc очистить память.

При этом принудительно gc.collect не надо вызывать.

Сильно не меняя ваш код, можно сделать так:

```
import itertools as itr
import threading
from queue import Queue, Empty
import time
import gc

class SimpleThread(threading.Thread):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, name, queue, result):
        super().__init__()
        SimpleThread.count += 1
        self.queue = queue
        self.name = name
        self.result = result
        self.stop = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop:
            try:
                item = self.queue.get_nowait()
                self.result.append(set(item))
                self.queue.task_done()
            except Empty:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        SimpleThread.count -= 1

class Calculate:
    def __init__(self, thread_cls, nthreads=16):
        self.result = []
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.threads = []
        for i in range(nthreads):
            t = thread_cls(f'№{i}',
                self.queue, self.result)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()
            self.threads.append(t)

    def __call__(self, input_array):
        for i in input_array:
            self.queue.put(i)
        self.queue.join()
        return self

    def stop(self):
        for t in self.threads:
            t.stop = True
            t.join()

arr = list(itr.combinations(range(1, 30), 6))
while True:
    calc = Calculate(SimpleThread)
    calc(arr)
    calc.stop() # Если закоментировать будет утечка памяти.
    i = input('Нажмите `q` для выхода, или `Enter` для продолжения:')
    del calc.queue, calc.result, calc
    print("Threads = ", SimpleThread.count)
    gc.collect()
    if i == 'q':
        break
```